# Microsoft Dynamics CRM - What is the OData url format to retrieve label of two option set attributes of an entity?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

The following Odata url retrieves attributes of an entity.

> http:// < host_name>/< org_name>/api/data/v8.1/EntityDefinitions(70816501-EDB9-4740-A16C-6A5EFBC05D84)/Attributes

The entity has few TwoOptionSet attributes. I want to retrieve the label for TrueOption and FalseOption. In the database, these values are stored in StringMapBase table.

How do I construct the OData query to retrieve these labels? Can you please guide me?

Thanks,
Vanathi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OData cannot be used to retrieve metadata. You need to use a SOAP request instead. However, when you are on Dynamics CRM 2016 you can use the Web API since it supports metadata queries.

For Dynamics 365/CRM 2016 you can find detailed information on getting attribute metadata using the Web API [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607522.aspx#bkmk_retrieveAttributes).

Comment: I am using Dynamics CRM 2016. Can you please let me know how to construct metadata query using Web API?

Comment: @Vanathi: I extended my answer.